# Triggering a Lambda by events from a MSK Cluster that is in a peered VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-msk

I'm trying to consume Kafka events from a customer's MSK cluster.

I cannot get it to run. I get intermittent errors:
PROBLEM: Connection error. Please check your event source connection configuration. If your event source lives in a VPC, try setting up a new Lambda function or EC2 instance with the same VPC, Subnet, and Security Group settings
Sometimes the "last processing result" reads: "Ok".

I cannot make sense of suggestions from the documentation. Does anyone have experience with this?

I have:

- Created a VPC in our account
- Our customer has created a peer connection to our VPC and I have accepted this
- Created a simple lambda handler
- Added a self-managed Kafka event trigger with the following properties:

  - Customer's broker addresses
  - Agreed upon topic
  - Entered the SASL-SCRAM credentials
  - Set the VPC to my VPC, subnets and security group (I cannot see/access the peered VPC of our customer)
- Set the VPC for the lambda handler to my VPC
- Created endpoints in our VPC for Lambda, STS and SecretManager

Comment: I feel like AWS Support should be able to assist with this, as they would have more access to see your configuration than we would

Answer (score 0):

Your customer should be running Lambda in their VPC.

After you peered VPCs, make sure you also [configured routing](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-dedicated-vpc).

Add inbound rules to MSK Security Group to allow access from the remote VPC.

Test your connectivity: ask the customer to telnet to the port 9096